# If $x,y\in \Bbb{R}^n,\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ then show there is a $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $x=\lambda y$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $x,y\in \Bbb{R}^n,\|x+y\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$ then show there is a $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $x=\lambda y$.

Comment: What if $y=0$ and $x \neq 0$?

Comment: Presumably this is the Euclidean norm? Because $\|e_1+e_2\|_1 = \|e_1\|_1 + \|e_2\|_1$.

Comment: Yes it is euclidean norm

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $||x+y||^2=(x+y)\cdot(x+y)=x\cdot x + y\cdot y + 2 x \cdot y=||x||^2+||y||^2+2 x \cdot y $ $= ||x||^2+||y||^2+2||x||||y||$, then $x \cdot y=||x||||y||\cos\theta=||x||||y||$, so $\cos \theta=1$

Comment: Cauchy Schwartz may help (basically the answer is the equality condition of cauchy schwartz)

Comment: Suppose $y \neq 0$ and write $x = \alpha y + z$ where $z \bot y$. Show $z=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $\| x\| = \sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle} $ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

---

We know that $$\| x + y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 + \| y \|^2 + 2\| x\|\|y \| $$
Then, we have that $$\langle x, x \rangle + \langle y, y \rangle + 2\sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle \cdot \langle y, y \rangle} $$ $$= \langle x + y, x + y \rangle = \langle x , x + y \rangle + \langle y, x + y \rangle = \langle x, x \rangle + \langle y , y\rangle + 2 \langle x, y \rangle   $$
By Cauchy Schwartz:
$$ 2|\langle x , y\rangle | \leqslant 2\sqrt{\langle x, x\rangle \cdot \langle y, y \rangle}  $$
Then it's the equality case of inequality. i.e., $x = \lambda y~$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}.$ Hence done!

Comment: $||x||=\sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}...$

Comment: Thanks @PAM1499. It was a typo

Answer (score 1):

If both $x,y$ are zero then $x=0 y$.

Suppose $y \neq 0$, and write $x=s y + z$, where $z \bot y$.

Then $\|x+y\|^2 = (s+1)^2 \|y\|^2 + \|z\|^2$, $\|x\|^2 = s^2 \|y\|^2 + \|z\|^2$
and $(\|x\|+\|y\|)^2 = s^2 \|y\|^2 + \|z\|^2 + \|y\|^2+2 |s| \|y\| \sqrt{s^2 \|y\|^2 + \|z\|^2}$.

Equating & simplifying yields $2s\|y\|^2 = 2 \|y\| \sqrt{s^2 \|y\|^2 + \|z\|^2}$.

This tells us that $s \ge 0$, and squaring both sides gives
$s^2 \|y\|^4 = s^2 \|y\|^4 + \|y\|^2 \|z\|^2$ from which we see that $z=0$.

Hence $x=sy$ with $s\ge 0$.